# Maximum of a complicated expression

Tags: inequality

For $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$ find the maximum of $a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt[3]{c}}$. Can somebody help? I  tried but nothing came to my mind. So zero progress in it. NOTE: Please do not use Lagrange multipliers or something too advanced. And try to give rigorous proofs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $b+c=\alpha$, $b+\sqrt[3]{c}=(\alpha-c)+\sqrt[3]{c}$ reach its maximum when $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}$ (it is sufficient to differentiate wrt to $c$), hence:
$$ a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt[3]{c}} \leq a + \sqrt{1-a+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}},$$
with equality when $c=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$. If now we set $d=\left(1+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)-a$, we have that the maximum of
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)-d+\sqrt{d}$$
is reached when $d=\frac{1}{4}$ (again, it is sufficient to differentiate wrt $d$).
Hence we have:
$$a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt[3]{c}} \leq \frac{5}{4}+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}} = 1.6349\ldots,$$
with equality in $a=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}, b=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, c=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

However, this optimum is reached when $b$ is negative!

If $a\in[0,1-1/\sqrt{27}]$, we can set $c=1/\sqrt{27}$ and exploit the monotonicity of $a+\sqrt{1-a+2/\sqrt{27}}$ to state that:

$$ a+ \sqrt{b+\sqrt[3]{c}} \leq 1-\frac{1}{3^{3/2}}+\frac{1}{3^{1/4}}=1.567\ldots,$$
with equality in $a=1-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}, b=0, c=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

If $a\in[1-1/\sqrt{27},1]$, then $\alpha=b+c\leq\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$, and the function $f(c)=\alpha-c+\sqrt[3]{c}$ is increasing over $[0,\alpha]$, reaching its maximum when $b=0$. So, if $a\in[1-1/\sqrt{27},1]$, we just have to find the maximum value of

$$ a + (1-a)^{1/6} $$

that is located in $a=1-\frac{1}{6^{6/5}}\in [1-1/\sqrt{27},1]$.
So we have:

$$ a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt[3]{c}} \leq 1-\frac{1}{6^{6/5}}+\frac{1}{6^{1/5}}=1.582\ldots$$

with equality reached in $a=1-\frac{1}{6^{6/5}},b=0,c=\frac{1}{6^{6/5}}$.

Comment: Yes, we already worked that out. The question is for positive $a,b,c$. So the extrema will occur at some boundary point.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Now I have completed the proof, the maximum occurs in $b=0$, indeed.

Comment: This more or less the same as proving that no stationary points occur inside the triangle $a,b,c\geq 0, a+b+c=1$, then studying the behaviour of the target function on the boundary $\{a=0\}\cup\{b=0\}\cup\{c=0\}$.

Comment: Very nice. Hard question.

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute $a = 1 - b - c$, and then have a function of two variables, $b$ and $c$, 
which you can optimize by setting partials to zero; you still have boundary conditions to worry about, but these are reasonably simple ones (e.g., $b > 0$, $c > 0$, $b+c < 1$). Did you try that? Where did it get you?

Comment: Hi but I don't want that type of solution as you can see from my post. I wanted you not to use Lagrange multipliers, so equating partials to zero might be easy and effective but I do not want that. So any other solution? Thanks for helping.

Comment: If this is not what you want, you can plot your function in $3D$'s ($c$ being eliminated and $0<a<1$, $0<b<1$). You can also make contour plots.

Comment: No I want an elementary proof of the maximum value. Not the methods mentioned above. If someone could give such a proof it would be helpful, nonetheless thanks a lot for the help you guys gave.

Comment: When you carry out this program of solving for $a$, and getting a function of $2$ variables, then setting both derivatives to $0$, and solving, one finds that $b$ is negative.

Comment: Assuming that @Rene is correct, then this function of 2 vars has nonzero gradient on the entire domain; that means that the function does not a achieve a max on the domain. (This works only because the domain described happens to be *open*; if the boundary conditions had been inequalities, you'd have more work to do.